# Eclipse(Android) - unfortunately HelloWorld has stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I get that error message everytime I try running my program. I have a fairly simple program, with two buttons. If you press one button it subtracts 1 from a number. If you press the add button it adds 1 to the number. I have no compiling errors and I'm fairly new to android. Any help would be great... Thanks!

Here is my code: (The main activity).

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView numberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        numberText.setText(String.valueOf(0));

        Button.OnClickListener listenerAdd = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView numberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.HomeScreenChangeAdd: {
                        String currText = numberText.getText().toString();
                        int curNumb = Integer.parseInt(currText);
                        int newNumb = curNumb +1;
                        String newText = String.valueOf(newNumb);
                        numberText.setText(newText);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Button.OnClickListener listenerSub = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView numberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.HomeScreenChangeSub: {
                        String currText = numberText.getText().toString();
                        int curNumb = Integer.parseInt(currText);
                        int newNumb = curNumb -1;
                        String newText = String.valueOf(newNumb);
                        numberText.setText(newText);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeScreenChangeAdd)).setOnClickListener(listenerAdd);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeScreenChangeSub)).setOnClickListener(listenerSub);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat error?

Comment: I get a lot of errors, but it says there is a nullpointer exception in the main activity

Comment: That is the problem :D just add the log and point the line then we will be able to help you, also you may want to post your layout xml

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it with FD_'s answer. Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure

- R.id.number,
- R.id.HomeScreenChangeAdd, and
- R.id.HomeScreenChangeSub

are included in `R.layout.activity_main`.

There is nothing else in your code that could crash the app *at startup*.